# One MOSFET slowly activates itself, the other won't fully activate

Tags: led, mosfet, raspberry-pi

I built the following circuit. +3.3V GPIOs and +5V driven by an RPi Zero. Common-anode RGB LED wired to three [IRLB3034](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb3034pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566027b22585) MOSFETs. These have Vgs(th)-min/max of 1V/2.5V.

The GPIOs are supposed to switch the MOSFETs to drive the LEDs on the 5V rail. Each LED is supposed to pull about 700 mA.

**Symptoms**

1. The red LED works perfectly.
2. The green LED was turning on as soon as the RPi was connected to power. I could stop this by shorting the gate to ground, but it would slowly build up again. Once the GPIO pin was explicitly set to 0 it would also stop. I "solved" this with a 100 Ω resistor from its gate to ground. Not really sure why this works.
3. The blue LED doesn't fully turn on. If I apply 5V to the gate it does, but 3.3V just doesn't cut it (maybe 10% brightness).

**Possibilities**

1. I've misunderstood something about the MOSFETs?
2. The blue MOSFET is broken?
3. Poor construction. I made this using an AdaFruit protoboard, big wires for the high-current and lots of solder. Have checked again and again for shorts.
4. Something else??

**Updates**

1. The 100 Ω resistor I added *only* for the green LED, and have now added to the diagram.
2. This is the LED: [link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2524) and [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2524/FD-9RGB-Y2.pdf)
3. The LED voltages are R: 2.5V, G: 3.6V, B: 3.6V.

[image: circuit-diagram]

Comment: "*I solved this with a 100 Ω resistor from its gate to ground.*" Your schematic shows 10k to ground. (This is much more sensible than 100 ohm.)

Comment: (1) Can we have a web link to your 700mA RGB LED? (2) If for Blue LED, Vgs = 5V works, but Vgs = 3V3 does not work, so it is likely the MOSFET does not fully turn on at Vgs = 3V3. (3) You remind me that once I bought two batches of IRL540N, one batch regular price, the other half of regular price. I later found that all the the regular ones work OK for Vgs = 3V3, but not all the cheapies.

Comment: Is your RGB LED module like this? AliExpress High Power 9W LED Chip 3W RGB 700mA With 6 pin 20mm Star PCB - US$20/10pcs
https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32774489769.html?spm=a2g0o.search0306.0.0.674d6d56X3I0DX&algo_pvid=e22b3318-174d-4ec1-b9bb-6434694ac5f0&algo_expid=e22b3318-174d-4ec1-b9bb-6434694ac5f0-3&btsid=0bb0624316132982650076282efdcc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: It is very difficult to balance the R, G, and B, particularly the B guy: https://i.imgur.com/FyJr2jL.jpg. Usually you need to use Constant Current Source chips to do the job.

Comment: @tlfong01 (1) I've added a link to the question (2) Seems to be the case. Possible to have such variation in three MOSFETs from the same source? (Random eBay seller.) Your anecdote (3) seems to suggest so! By "balance" you mean in terms of light output? I'm not too worried about that (though it would be nice), but just want it to turn on properly!

Comment: Vgs threshold is not the right specification to use. In the data sheet there will be Rds(on) values for various values of Vgs. *That* is the key specification.

Comment: @Transistor I've added the extra 100 Ω resistor to the diagram.

Comment: OK, but now you've a 100:100 potential divider so you can only get half your GPIO output voltage on the FET so you're making it difficult to turn it on. The 10k should be more than adequate.

Comment: @PeterSmith Rds(on) at Vgs==4.5V is ~2 mΩ. In my case Vgs≈3.3V (I think?), but surely not enough difference to cause a huge resistance?

Comment: @Transistor the green LED (that has the extra resistor) still turns on fine. It's the blue LED that doesn't fully activate...

Comment: Datasheet : " Very Low RDS(ON) at 4.5V " translation : 3.3V won't cut it, at least, not reliably.

Comment: Question need editing: No way you can get 700mA through 4.3kOhm with just 5V. What is wrong: current or resistance? 100Ohm to gnd is way too high a load for the RPi output. Need kohm values.

Comment: @Peter Smith, I agree the Vgs(th) number is too vague. So I sometimes stare at the figures: https://i.imgur.com/uM1lblF.jpeg. :)

Comment: @HenningLarsen sorry, when I made a different edit to the diagram I somehow messed up the resistance values. Fixed now.

Comment: @BrianDrummond but why does the red one work perfectly and the green have the *opposite* behavior? Or because I'm ~1.2V below ideal, all bets are off and the behavior becomes unpredictable? (And the green one just caused by a twitchy gate). Want to propose that as an Answer so I can choose it? (If you think that's the case.)

Comment: @carderne typical red LEDs have a forward voltage of about 2V or so. Green around 3V and blue somewhere above 4V when cool. That explains why the different parts have different amounts of output. Those values are for current of around 10mA

Comment: @PeterSmith have just added the LED voltages from the datasheet to the question. Should have stated this up front. The blue and green LEDs have the same forward voltage (at least according to the datasheet). So this *shouldn't* explain the different outputs.

Comment: @carderne If you measure the gate voltage for the MOSFET for the blue LED, do you get the expected value or could it be that the 100 Ω resistor to ground is not where you intended?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just measured and got Vgs (gate to ground) pretty much 3.3V, so don't think that's it. Touching ground with my multimeter somehow set the red and green LEDs burning full brightness, not sure what that's about.

Comment: @carderne, a couple of quick comments: (1) I used to buy from TaoBao (AliExpress' domestic branch), (a) Some of their shops have two options - (iii) "Same lot/ same bin", usually means from same wafer, perhaps 20% more expensive (ii) "scattered" means not from same lot, but purchase order"left overs".  Usually if you buy a whole "tube" of say 25/40 items, you will get similar grade chips.  (2) The story I told earlier was about IRF540N/IRL540N. I noticed that the fake IRL540N IC marking was poor quality, so I suspected they were IRF (7V Vgs(th)) remarkded as 3V3/5V0 logical level Vgs(th).

Comment: (2) By colour "balance" I mean same level of "brightness". (2) But even if from same bin/grade, the spec does not guarantee much, because brightness Lm varies muchly with current If, which often varies drastically with voltage Vf. That is why people uses CCS (Constant Current Source) with PWM to get better colour balance/blending. Ref: https://i.imgur.com/9WKD5xv.jpeg

Comment: @cardeme, In case you find it difficult to tune the 3W x 3 = 9W RGB LEDs, you might like to read the following newbie friendly tutorial. Me newbie learned the reason and importance of Constant Current Control of power RGB LED from this short tutorial. ***1 Watt LED Pinout, Features, Uses & Datasheet - Components101, 2018mar17***
https://components101.com/diodes/1-watt-led

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01! For my application the the brightness/balance is not too important, as I can control it in software if it's not too pleasing. But fully understand a constant current source would make my life much easier! Seems like I got a bad/different MOSFET (as you suggest) and/or I need to choose a MOSFET that is optimum closer to my V level.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage drop across the resistors in series to the green and blue LED might be part of the problem.

If each LED really needs 700 mA, the voltage drop across the resistor for the blue LED would be 1.4V. This would leave 3.6V for the blue LED forward voltage and the Vds of the MOSFET. This might just be enough but I wouldn't bet on it.

For green, the voltage drop across the resistor would be about 2.5V, leaving only 2.5V for the LED and MOSFET's Vds. This probably isn't enough.

And as @Transitor recommended, I also wouldn't use the 100 Ohm from Gate green to GND. Besides the potential divider this will draw quite a lot of current from your GPIO. You should alos check if your 5V supply can source the 2.1A for all three LEDs.

Some ideas to solve the LED issue:

- Make resistor green and blue smaller. Probably the easiest solution but with ill defined LED currents.
- Use a BJT with a resistor in the emitter as a constant current source providing 700mA. This however might need more than a 5V supply.

Comment: I accidentally swapped the resistance values in the diagram, please see corrected now. They are calculate so that the resistor and LED together consume the full 5V at ~700mA. Is that wrong? Do I need additional voltage for the MOSFET Vds? But if that's the case why does blue struggle when red and green don't? And why does blue suddenly work when I apply 5V to gate. (Note that green and blue LEDs have the same forward voltage.)

Comment: I just took a look at your MOFSETs data sheet, the Vds is probalby negligible small. Regarding your updated schematic, I see 3.6Ohm for blue and green, is that correct?

Anyway.. considering the forward voltage you posted and neglecting the Vds of the MOSFET, the voltage drop across the green and blue resistors is 1.4V, meaning about 400mA for the LEDs (if 3.6Ohm is correct). Looking at the LEDs datasheet this probably is enough to turn them on. Why blue works with 5V at the gate is weird. I don't think it's the transistors Rdson. Maybe something wrong wired in the blue part?

Comment: Wow I'm sorry it's not my day; I mixed up the resistance values again... Thanks for your help. Going to investigate again with a multimeter but I'm 90% sure blue is wired correct.

Comment: See if you can find a complete data sheet, your link does not show forward voltage.  At 700mA I would expect the forward voltage of the LED to be much more. Many times they are constructed with die in series.  Your circuit diagram looks good especially the gate resistors. However I would suggest changing the 5V to maybe 12v and recalculating your cathode resistors. Start with a 1K and measure the voltage drop across the LED, this will be approximately the forward voltage. Measure drain to source on the MOSFET they should be less then 0.03 volts. Main thing have fun!

Comment: Hi @Gil, I just added the complete datasheet. And learned something new! (Or something I long ago forgot.) You're right, the datasheet shows that above ~500ma, the forward V is around 3.3V (instead of 2.5V) for red, and 4.3V (instead of 3.6V) for green/blue. So I should definitely recalculate my resistors to get the brightness I'm looking for. But this still doesn't explain why blue isn't turning on! (Just testing with 1 Ω and marginally brighter but no big difference.)

Comment: Unfortunately 5V is the most I have without completely changing the setup. It's an RPi Zero running on a USB charger, would have to start from scratch to get a 12V rail...

Comment: I believe you do not have enough voltage on the blue LED. When it is turned on,(not necessarily lit) measure the voltage on both leads of the LED, it is below the VF rating. Check the voltage of the MOSFET relative to ground, it should be less than 0.02 volts, if not you are not properly driving it or it is not in the circuit correctly. I am sorry to say but I believe you need a boost converter if 5V is all that is available because of the blue led. Try swapping leds and see if it is consistently the blue led.  In each case measure the voltage across the LED and note of it. are any backwards?

Comment: Thanks @Gil for the advice. However, the blue LED is driven just fine when I apply 5V to the MOSFET gate, so unless I'm misunderstanding, I don't think the problem is there... I'm going to buy a new set of MOSFETs (with slightly lower Vgs-th etc) and calculate new resistance values based on the complete datasheet as you pointed out, hopefully that will get me there!

Comment: Sorry to say you are mistooken. When you raise the VGS to 5V it works, at 3.3 it does not. This conforms to the data sheet. You are not properly enhancing it with 3V. The lower Vgs MOSFET will fix the problem.